# ColCade Masonry Grid | JavaScript - Gap Between Flexbox Rows - How do I remove it?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, grid, masonry

I'm stuck in a CSS issue with the ColCade masonry grid by [ColCade](https://github.com/desandro/colcade).

Look at the image (Flexbox Gap Between Rows - Indicated):

[image: 2]

I've tried to get rid of the space/gap between these rows but can't seem to find a workaround. :( The grid seems to be working fine. The issue is only with CSS. There are these gaps I can see while inspecting the grid rows with the Chrome Dev tool but cannot figure out what is applying these gaps. I've zeroed the margin/padding for these elements.

Code Snippet below;

```
      <div class="grid" data-colcade="columns: .grid-col, items: .grid-item">

            <!-- columns -->
            <div class="grid-col grid-col--1"></div>
            <div class="grid-col grid-col--2"></div>
            <div class="grid-col grid-col--3"></div>
            <div class="grid-col grid-col--4"></div>
            <!-- items -->
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
                </div>
                <img src="/assets/grid_img_01.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <!-- items -->
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
                </div>
                <img src="/assets/grid_img_02.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <!-- items -->
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
                </div>
                <img src="/assets/grid_img_03.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <!-- items -->
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
                </div>
                <img src="/assets/grid_img_04.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Please consider editing your question and rewrote your code as a snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This issue was resolved! Thanks!

Solution: I was having trouble with the line height on grid items. Set the line height to 0px and the gaps are no more there. :)